# What is summaryQty Parameter in Item.php

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, addtocart

In Item.php file in app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/ there is the function

```
checkQuoteItemQty($qty, $summaryQty, $origQty = 0) ...
```

What is different in qty parameter and summaryQty parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the function itself, you will find the description of the parameters just above the function.

```
/**
 * Checking quote item quantity
 *
 * Second parameter of this method specifies quantity of this product in whole shopping cart
 * which should be checked for stock availability
 *
 * @param mixed $qty quantity of this item (item qty x parent item qty)
 * @param mixed $summaryQty quantity of this product
 * @param mixed $origQty original qty of item (not multiplied on parent item qty)
 * @return Varien_Object
 */
```

So, here `$summaryQty` is the total number of current product in whole cart. It will consist of all the instances of current product in different parent products.

Suppose you have a simple product added in multiple parent products like in configurable product, in bundle product or in grouped product and a customer buys one from configurable product and one from bundle product, `$summaryQty` will be the quantity of current simple product from both the parent products.

If the value of `$summaryQty` exceeds total number of available quantity of the product, it will display error message by below code

```
if (!$this->checkQty($summaryQty) || !$this->checkQty($qty)) {
    $message = Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('The requested quantity for "%s" is not available.', $this->getProductName());
    $result->setHasError(true)
        ->setMessage($message)
        ->setQuoteMessage($message)
        ->setQuoteMessageIndex('qty');
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: I have add last 1 product qty in cart but when place order it show error. Requested qty is not available. The summaryQty value is 2 when place order. Please suggest me how to fix this issue. Thanks

Comment: Do you have only one product in cart? Or there is any other product added in cart?

Comment: Yes  I have added only one product in cart and it's stock qty is only one. But when place order on frontend it's showing error.

Comment: @RakeshPatidar, did you try creating a new product with qty 1 and adding the same in cart?